# codeigniter email send incorrect link

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I just want to ask because I tried to send an email with a link. The problem is the link.

```
http://mysite/samplesite/login/confirm_email/qwVBEkXFqCp9BQLvKWNBPpWzOo2Ryx
```

becomes

```
http://mysite/samplesite/login/confirm_email/qwVBEkXFqCp=BQLvKWNBPpWzOo2Ryx
```

As you notice, the 9 became =.

I tried changing my mailtype as text and it work but how to solve it having mailtype as html?

Answer (score 0):

I use the PHP Mailer for send email... Thats already makes the necessary settings for authentication and integrity of your email code in html. Always works for me.

Download PHPMailer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/

How to use: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/